# Save a dictionary<String, [customStruct]> to userDefaults

Tags: xcode, swift

How do I save a dictionary to the NSUserDefaults? Whenever I try to I receive an error message which says that my dictionary doesn't conform to the 'AnyObject' protocol.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject([String: [customStruct]](), forKey: "someKey")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apple documentation (you should read it):

"The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData."

So if `customStruct` is not one of these you will need to convert it to one of these, probably `NSData` or `NSString`.